# The first and the last

Tags: hadith-interpretation, authenticity

> Abu Huraira (ra) narrates from the Messenger of Allah (May Peace be upon him) that he said: When Allah created Adam (Peace be upon him) He informed him of his descendants, at this Adam (Peace be upon him) saw superiority of some over others, then he saw me towards the end in form of an illuminating nur he (adam) said: O my Lord who is this? The Lord replied: This is your son Ahmed who is **the first and the last** and he will be first to do intercession. (Bayhaqi, Dala’il un Nubuwwah: Volume 005, Page No. 483)

Is the hadith above authentic? What exactly is the meaning of the bolded parts?